# Highcharts - Categories and Series alignment

Tags: mysql, highcharts, alignment, categories, series

I have a MySQL table containing some data with the following format:

```
Year, Month, Value
2012, Nov, 33
2012, Dez, 34
2013, Jan, 35
...
2013, Dez, 40
```

and so on...

I want to do a column chart, where my categories are the Months (from Jan to Dez) and where I plot my data, [2012, 33], [2012, 34], etc.

I'm retrieving my data from MySQL with a group_concat from values, by year.

The problem: When I plot my data, if I have information to every month of every Year (since my categories go from Jan to Dez for some year at least) everything goes OK. But, if like in 2012, where I only have data for Nov and Dez, my chart gets messed up because the data is assumed as being from Jan and Fev (for example).

How can I solve this? There must be a better way than adding zeros to the string data I suppose. Maybe a different type of MySQL query? Or plotting data differently?

I appreciate any thoughts on this!

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post it as a live demo like http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: How your output data looks like ?